# How to implement setting value of a specific element in linked list?

Tags: rust, linked-list

I'm learning Rust by implementing a single linked list. I've followed the 2nd chapter in [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/first.html). I want to implement a function to set value of a specific element in the list by its index. Here's my code so far:

```rust
pub struct List {
    head: Link,
}

enum Link {
    Empty,
    More(Box<Node>),
}

struct Node {
    elem: i32,
    next: Link,
}

impl List {
    /// Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.
    pub fn set(&mut self, index: usize, elem: i32) -> Result<(), &str> {
        // Start from the first node where index is 0
        let mut id: usize = 0;
        let mut curr_node: &Link = &self.head;
        while let Link::More(mut node) = curr_node {
            curr_node = &node.next;
            id += 1;
            if id == index {
                node.elem = elem;
                break;
            }
        }
        if id < index {
            return Err("Invalid index");
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

The compiler emits 2 compile errors:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `curr_node.0` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/lib.rs:21:42
   |
21 |         while let Link::More(mut node) = curr_node {
   |                              --------    ^^^^^^^^^
   |                              |
   |                              data moved here
   |                              move occurs because `node` has type `Box<Node>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0597]: `node.next` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:22:25
   |
21 |         while let Link::More(mut node) = curr_node {
   |                                          --------- borrow later used here
22 |             curr_node = &node.next;
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
28 |         }
   |         - `node.next` dropped here while still borrowed
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ff99d4f3771cbb449954d272a88dc428)

How should I implement this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw the title of your question I immediately wanted to post a link to that "Learning Rust via too many linked lists" book, but I see you're already on to that :)

Ah, it's all so very messy, isn't it? Well in your case the solution is quite simple.

First, the type of `curr_node` should be `&mut Link` and thus needs to also be initialized with `&mut self.head` because we need a *mutable* reference.

Next, in your `while` loop you are using *pattern matching* to bind the value of the node to your variable `node`. However, pattern matching by default *moves* the matched value into the variable, and that's why the compiler complains: You can't just up and move elements out of a struct.

Instead of moving, we just want to grab a *reference* to the node, so we say `while let Link::More(ref mut node) = curr.node { ... }`

and then finally `curr_node = &mut node.next` because again we need a *mutable* reference.

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=30dea5613f4a43a74e8cc12bb8e4c8a3)